# Richfaces - How can i store variable list of picklist?

Tags: richfaces

I was playing with the `picklist` component of `Richfaces 3.x`. 
The "basic" use is kinda straightforward.

I would like to display several `picklist` components on one page.
My problem is that the number of `picklist` is variable, based on a selection in a previous page.

So I can have 1, 2 or more `picklist` in one page. The `selectItems` data is the same so it's all good. (it would be ok even if it was different, actually, as i could pass a parameter)

I was thinking about storing the data in the backing bean as a `Map<String, List<String>>` but, how can i do that in xhtml?

Usually we write up something like that :

```
<rich:pickList value="#{backingBean.pickListSelectedItems}"  > ...
```

Is it possible to do it dynamically ?
Or maybe there is a workaround available...

thanks.